# Transporting projects from xcode 4.02 - 4.3

Tags: xcode, version, transfer

Good day - several days have passed while i was trying to transport my `xcode 4.02` project (from mac os x 6) to `xcode 4.3` (mac os x lion)
So it is complete fail(( The problem is [Apple Mach-o Linker id Error]

Problem starts when i add

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 //This one   BaseView* testView = [[BaseView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f,     320.0f, 460.0f)];

 //   [self.window addSubview:testView];    

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; 

}
```

and it gives me this error

`Ld "/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Табло_Аэропортов-eijvojjtdhkznwhcqentolpelkxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Табло Аэропортов.app/Табло Аэропортов" normal i386
    cd "/Users/alex/Desktop/Табло Аэропортов"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Табло_Аэропортов-eijvojjtdhkznwhcqentolpelkxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Табло_Аэропортов-eijvojjtdhkznwhcqentolpelkxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Табло_Аэропортов-eijvojjtdhkznwhcqentolpelkxm/Build/Intermediates/Табло Аэропортов.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Табло Аэропортов.build/Objects-normal/i386/Табло Аэропортов.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -o "/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Табло_Аэропортов-eijvojjtdhkznwhcqentolpelkxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Табло Аэропортов.app/Табло Аэропортов"`

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BaseView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Seems like some problem with quarts core or mac os x version. Dunna know what to do(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BaseView" says that your BaseView class hasn't been compiled into the project.  Select your target, click on the build phases tab, open the section called compile sources, and add the missing .m file.

Comment: Thanks)))! Well now it's time to learn about new arc who hates my autoreleases retains and so on(